# Using jamon.war on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jamon

I'm using [JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/), and I want to use the `jamon.war` to monitor my app. However, my app and the `jamon.war` app have different classloaders, and therefore they don't see each other's static variables (where the data is stored, as far as I understand). I am getting the proper data when I call `MonitorFactory.getReport()` in my app.

How to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I had jamon-xx.jar in my `WEB-INF/lib`. When I remove it (and have it only in tomcat's lib dir), it is loaded by the tomcat classloader (which I guess is a parent of all application classloaders), and so the two applications can share the static fields.

Comment: Right, if you share a jar between different applications, you should do it through the tomcat/lib directory. Each webapp has in fact its own classloader, but you can put them in communication through the Common classloader. Have a look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Comment: You can observe the same problem with EhCache shared `CacheManager` (the same manager for all WARs in Tomcat) - if the `ehcache.jar` is bundled with each application, each one will have its own `CacheManager` since EhCache uses `static` field to share manager... Once `ehcache.jar` is placed in `/lib` directory both application share the same `CacheManager` and caches.